# Why my app throws Error - 504 on Google play store when installing on some devices?

Tags: android, google-play, release

So I'm getting this error on devices with android version < Oreo. On devices that runs Oreo there's no problem with my app. Could be about user permissions? Then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that one of my packages name dont have lower cases:

The folder(package)name was Activityes and I changed to activityes with lower cases.

Answer (score 0):

504 might have many possible reason. My personal experience is about signing procedure.
Are you using `zipalign`? or manual signing?
If yes, make sure you sign your app **after** you zipalign it. If not, maybe you should paste your `gradle` file.

some of the other possible hints are : 
Are you using any native libs? 
Have you downgrade any version? 
Can you install the apk directly?

Comment: Thank for your answer I appreciate! :)